# whole document custom font size

Tags: fontsize

I need a way to set the font size to any custom value like what can be achieved with `\changefontsize` from `fontsize` package. The problem of `fontsize` is that it does not affect the font size in the header and footer. There is also the `extsizes` package, but in my quick test, using `extarticle` documentclass only the header and footer have been affected.

here is my mwe:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{fontsize,fix-cm,fancyhdr}
\changefontsize{18}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[R]{header}
\fancyfoot[C]{\thepage{}}

\begin{document}
document body
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general you want to tell LaTeX what font size you want in headers and footers.

```
\RequirePackage{fix-cm}
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{fontsize,fancyhdr}
\changefontsize{18}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[R]{\footnotesize header \fontname\font}
\fancyfoot[C]{\footnotesize\thepage}
\setlength{\headheight}{18pt}

\begin{document}
document body
\end{document}
```

[image]

Otherwise, fix a bug in `fancyhdr.sty` that uses `\@normalsize` when it shouldn't.

```
\RequirePackage{fix-cm}
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{fontsize,fancyhdr}
\changefontsize{18}

\makeatletter
\let\@normalsize\normalsize
\makeatother

\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[R]{header \fontname\font}
\fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}
\pagestyle{fancy}

\begin{document}
document body
\end{document}
```

[image]

Explanation: older (in the sense of *very old*) versions of LaTeX used `\@normalsize`, but nowadays only `\normalsize` should be used anywhere.

Of course, you'll have to cope with the important warning

```
Package fancyhdr Warning: \headheight is too small (12.0pt):
(fancyhdr)                Make it at least 21.59993pt, for example:
(fancyhdr)                \setlength{\headheight}{21.59993pt}.
(fancyhdr)                You might also make \topmargin smaller to compensate:
(fancyhdr)                \addtolength{\topmargin}{-9.59993pt}.
```

Comment: no, i want to set the document font size such that, that one setting is affecting the header and footer too.

Comment: in your solution, look, the size is not the same for the document body and the header.

Comment: @user1850133 then replace `\footnotesze` by `\normalsize` you need it to trigger the fontsize function correctly.

Comment: @user1850133 I added a way. But you should set the size anyway. Your first comment was a bit rude, wasn't it? Something like “Sorry, I'd like to…” would have avoided the rudeness.

Comment: yes that works when the `\let\@normalsize\normalsize` is after the `\changefontsize...` command

Comment: has this "bug" been reported?

Answer (score 0):

What you want (one only setting for all) is:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,17pt]{extarticle}
```

or

```
\documentclass[a4paper,17pt]{extarticle}
```

Unfortunately, you cannot use 18pt here, only the same sizes that using extsizes:, i.e., 8pt, 9pt, 10pt, 11pt, 12pt, 14pt, 17pt, and 20pt

If you want exactly 18pt you will need a scalable font (e.g., the libertine `libertine` package) and use a Koma class:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,fontsize=18pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{libertine}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[R]{header}
\fancyfoot[C]{\thepage{}}
\begin{document}
document body
\end{document}
```

However, wouldn't it be easier for you to simply add `\changefontsize{18}` also in the footer and the header?